# Simply connected algebraic group and quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

If everything is well define, does it exist a result like : (maybe some hypothesis are missing)

"Let $G$ be a simply connected algebraic group over a field $k$ and $N$ a normal algebraic subgroup of $G$ which is also simply connected. Then, $G/N$ is simply connected as quotient algebraic group." ?

Even if it's false, which book would you advise to learn stuff about simply connected, unipotent and solvable algebraic groups ?

Edit: Here G is connected, N is actually its derived group, and I say "simply connected" to say : "Does not have nontrivial etale group covering", where an etale group covering is an epimorphism of algebraic groups whose kernel (in the category of $k$-group scheme) is finite and etale

Comment: You have to be very careful about what you mean by fundamental group. What definition are you using? Any time you can use the lefschetz principle or the long exact sequence on \pi_1^et this is trivially true as long as N is connected. 

If G is any algebraic group its not clear how we should define its \pi_1.

Comment: Sorry, here $G$ is connected, $N$ is actually its derived group, and I say "simply connected" to say : "Does not have nontrivial etale group covering" (I'm even not using the fundamental group here), where an etale group covering is an epimorphism of algebraic groups whose kernel (in the category of $k$-group scheme) is finite and etale.

Comment: So you want that PSl_p simply connected in char p then?

Comment: Anyway a finite etale cover of an algebraic group is also naturally an algebraic group, thus your notion of etale covering is the same as a surjective finite etale cover of G, N. So this all follows from the homotopy long exact sequence on pi_1.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know the hopotpy long exact sequence on $\pi_1$. I can have a look at it of course if we cannot answer otherwise. But you are saying this is true right ?

Comment: Yes I am saying if you have a morphism of connected schemes p: X \to Y which is proper with geometrically connected fibers, then there is a map \pi_1^et(X_s) \to \pi_1^{et}(X, t) \to \pi_1^{et}(Y, s) \to 0, in particular if X is simply connected, then so is the quotient of X by any connected group.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer! I have to work more on that though because this is not clear for me.

Comment: It comes from this classical statement in algebraic topology: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_of_homotopy_groups